# C++ a default constructor of a class calling another default constructor of another class

Tags: c++, constructor

I have 2 classes Class A and B. I am trying to use Class B's default constructor to call class A's default constructor to intialize the values of class A in class B.

```
class A
{
    A();    
    int x;
}

A::A()
{
    //initialized x
    x=10;
}

class B
{
    B();
    A aobj;
}

B::B()
{
    //Calling class A's  default constructor to initialize B's aobj.
    aobj();
}
```

I received a no match call to '(aobj)'. Please help me to resolve.

Comment: You aren't calling the constructor of `A`, you're trying to invoke the function call operator (`A::operator()()`) which doesn't exist. Constructors are unnamed special member functions can cannot be directly accessed like that.

Comment: Probably you should get yourself acquainted with the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to explicitly default construct members as that happens automatically unless you explicitly construct the member otherwise. In case you want to really construct a member explicitly, whether it is default construction or something else, you'll need to put your initialization into the member initializer list:

```
B::B()
    : aobj() {
}
```

The expression `aobj()` in the body of a function tries to use the function call operator on the member `aobj`. Doing so may be reasonable, e.g., when `aobj` is of type `std::function<void()>`.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a statement, `aobj()` does not try to construct the `aobj` variable, rather it attempts to call it using the `operator()` operator overload.

Instead, try doing the construction in `B::B()`'s initializer list:

```
B::B() : aobj()
{
}
```

But note that this is redundant, since the default constructor for member objects will be called implicitly if omitted from the initializer list.  That is, this constructor would do the exact same thing:

```
B::B() { }
```